# /var/log/messages contains series of ^@ char

Tags: linux, logs

I am running kernel 4.1.15, sometimes in /var/log/messages i am getting series of ^@ characters. Normally the content is ok in /var/log/messages it is just for once for few seconds i got these junk characters. Any idea why?

Comment: i get this kind of things when i experience unexpected reboots or strange behavior of the machines, most often caused by hardware error

Comment: What are you using to view the file (`cat`, `less`, `more`, `head`, `vi`, ...)? "once for a few seconds" -- what does that mean? You ran `cat /var/log/messages` several times in a row, and then after X seconds the issue stopped happening? What is writing to the file (syslog-ng, rsyslog, ...)? Do you have anything like `logrotate` rotating it out? If so what's the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

That is the ASCII code for the [Null Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

It shouldn't be an actual issue with logging. I would guess it is an issue with whatever program is outputting to /var/log/messages.

Some terminal emulator programs won't output character sequences correctly due to character encoding. Make sure you're using one (or connected with one) that matches your locale, such as UTF-8.